# I am trying to extract a newspaper data by clicking at next button to get more links

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract business standard newspaper economy section data by clicking on the links but I am failing to do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Here Chrome is used

# URL of website
url = "https://www.business-standard.com/search?q=economy"

# Opening the website
driver.get(url)

# #button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#']"))).click()
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'Next')]]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You need to close the floating banner
2. You are using a wrong locator.
3. there is no need to define `button` element on the left side when you click the element returned instantly.

This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Here Chrome is used

# URL of website
url = "https://www.business-standard.com/search?q=economy"

# Opening the website
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btnno"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='next-colum']"))).click()
```

Comment: Now it is working but How to extract links from next pages ... I am still in difficulty

Comment: I think we can do this too, but this is a new, additional question.

Comment: What you should do now is to ask a new question for that (and accept back this one)

Comment: wait for 90 mins

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. Anyway, each question here should be about 1 specific issue. It is not me who set these rules here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103427/selenium-is-opening-the-browser-but-how-to-get-links-of-the-news-articles-by-cli

Comment: here is the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241983/discussion-between-raj-and-prophet).