# Selenium is opening the browser but How to get links of the news articles by clicking at load more button continuously

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get all the news links of articles by clicking the load more or next button from the given newspaper link but I am failing to do so in continuation...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Here Chrome is used

# URL of website
url = "https://www.business-standard.com/search?q=economy"

# Opening the website
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btnno"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='next-colum']"))).click()
```

Comment: How are you getting the links on the initial page, before clicking the `next` button?

Comment: To the economy page I am getting it manually, because I need specific section of newspaper

Comment: Please show us how you doing this with a code, then we will be able to expand that code to more complex with paginations

Comment: by hitting this link - https://www.business-standard.com/search?q=economy

Comment: No, please show us your full code, not in comments, in the question body

Comment: I was doing it using beautifulsoup earlier for other newspapers where pages move by page number